# How do for-in loops in swift work?

Tags: swift, for-loop

I've used them, I'm familiar with the code and read a number tutorials but I still don't understand exactly how they work in that I can't run through my head what I'm doing and ultimately what I want to achieve, as opposed to say an if statement which can be read in English quite well.

`For-loops` have always been something I've struggled with through lack of understanding, can someone offer some insight please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for-in loop performs a set of statements for each item in a range or collection. Swift also provides two range operators `a..<b` and `a...b`, as a shortcut for expressing a range of values.

```
// prints 1-10
for i in 1...10 {
    print(i)
}


// This way has been removed in Swift 3 so use the above
for var i = 1; i <= 10; i+=1 {
    print(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The for-in loop is used for iterations on numbers, items in an array or characters in a string.

```
//I want my var res to be equal to 10:
for var nb = 0 in 0..10 {
    nb += 1
    print("my nb is \(nb)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand for loops, one needs to understand the need for repeating lines of code (an unrolled loop) for a bunch of sequential numbers or array elements, etc.  A "for-loop" tells the processor to do most of the repetition for you, without the need for you to copy-paste all those nearly identical lines of code a whole bunch (maybe millions or billions) of times.

A "for in" loop lets you specify the range (of numbers or array elements, etc.) over which you want the repetition, so the code doesn't go on repeating forever.